# Can't pass the result of a generic method to another method?

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple generic method that creates a list of n elements and returns it:

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public static <T> List<T> init(int n) {
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
        while (n --> 0) l.add(null);
        return l;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> x = init(5);
        f(x);
    }
    public static void f(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println("l: " + l);
    }
}
```

It works as expected:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
l: [null, null, null, null, null]
```

But if I eliminate the extra variable:

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public static <T> List<T> init(int n) {
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
        while (n --> 0) l.add(null);
        return l;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(init(5));
    }
    public static void f(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println("l: " + l);
    }
}
```

it no longer compiles

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:9: f(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) in A cannot be applied to (java.util.List<java.lang.Object>)
        f(init(5));
        ^
1 error
```

Why?

But yet this works:

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public static <T> List<T> init(int n) {
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
        while (n --> 0) l.add(null);
        return l;
    }
    public static <T> T id(T t) {
        return t;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> x = init(5);
        f(id(x));
    }
    public static void f(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println("l: " + l);
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Apparently, your second example will work in [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java relies on inference to figure out what the type variables are in a situation where they are not explicitly defined.

In your first example:

```
List<String> x = init(5);
f(x);
```

The compiler infers that you are calling `<String> init` because `x` is a `List<String>`.

---

In your second example:

```
f(init(5));
```

The compiler cannot infer that you are calling `<String> init` because you are not explicitly telling it (via `A. <String> init(5)`) nor are you assigning it to an appropriate variable.

---

In your third example:

```
List<String> x = init(5);
f(id(x));
```

The compiler infers that you are calling `<List<String>> id` which returns a `List<String>` to `f`.

---

The compiler isn't too smart about generic inference. Unless you explicitly state what the type arguments are, either by using a variable or by directly passing them to the method, it will not be able to figure them out.

Here are the relevant sections of the JLS if you're curious about the specifics:

- [JLS §15.12.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7)
- [JLS §15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8)

Comment: It is worth noting that target type generic inference will be added in [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101).

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the extra variable the compiler has no way to infer the type parameter `T` when calling `init(5)`. It assumes `T` to be `Object` and hence the compiler error.

With the extra variable declared as a `List<String> x` the compiler infer `T` to be `String`.

Comment: If it has no way to infer the type parameter then how does it know that binding `List<String> x` to the result is valid? Is it implicitly casting? I thought Java doesn't do that.

Comment: It has no way to infer if don't give the compiler a clue. When you say that the type of x is a `List<String>` you give it a clue to infer that the return type from `init` is a `List<String>`.

Comment: But there is a clue, which is that the value returned from `init` is being passed to `f` which takes `List<String>`. How is this different than `Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(123))`?

Answer (score 2):

First, the fix;

```
f(A.<String>init(5)); // compiles
```

Now, why: The original code compiled because java could *infer* the type due to being assigned to a typed variable. But inference doesn't work when being *passed* to a typed parameter.

The fix uses the syntax for explicitly specifying the type when calling a typed method.

Comment: Beat me to it, so i will just enhance your answer with a [working example](http://ideone.com/KQ7F5v)

Answer (score 1):

```
f(init(5));
```

This calls `f()` with the argument directly received from `init()`. However, `init()` now returns a `List` of `T`. With `T` not specified Java just uses `Object` because it is the base class for all objects. `List<Object>` is not `List<String>`, so the method signature and the parameters don't match.

```
List<String> x = init(5);
f(x);
```

Here you are putting the `List<Object>` to a variable of the type `List<String>`. This converts it, because `String` is of course a subclass of `Object`. Also the conversion succeeds because `null` can also be converted to `String` as well as any other class. Then `x`'s type matches the method signature.

```
List<String> x = init(5);
f(id(x));
```

This is basically the same thing. Now, because `x` has the type `List<String>`, `id()`'s type `T` is `String`. This way the return value of `id()` is also `List<String>`, which matches the signature.

Answer (score 0):

In both the first and the third example, you stated that you are talking about a `List<String>`, yet on the second one you said `f(init(5))`, which could be a `List<Integer>`. I'm not 100% that's the **only** reason, but check it out :)